# How can I solved the problem with Vue 3, using formkit

Tags: vue.js, formkit

I have problem with vue 3 project using vite and @formkit/vue

> Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "@formkit/vue". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".
> The web application run ok on local, but error on production with nginx run on docker.

The library which I use:

```
"dependencies": {
    "insane": "^2.6.2",
    "marked": "^4.1.0",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "pinia": "^2.0.22",
    "vue": "^3.2.39",
    "vue-final-modal": "4.0.1",
    "vue-i18n": "^9.2.2",
    "vue-router": "^4.1.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@cypress/vue": "^4.2.0",
    "@formkit/vue": "^1.0.0-beta.12",
    "@intlify/unplugin-vue-i18n": "^0.8.1",
    "@mutoe/eslint-config-preset-vue": "~1.4.0",
    "@pinia/testing": "^0.0.14",
    "@testing-library/cypress": "^8.0.3",
    "@types/marked": "^4.0.7",
    "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^3.1.0",
    "@vue/tsconfig": "^0.1.3",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.13",
    "concurrently": "^7.4.0",
    "cypress": "^10.8.0",
    "eslint": "^8.23.1",
    "eslint-plugin-cypress": "^2.12.1"
 },
```

Please help me!

Comment: Can you show your @formkit/vue implementation?

Comment: You should move `@formkit/vue` to your `dependencies` since it's needed in prod.